# Confusion over the application of rank-nullity theorem for the proof of Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem

Tags: matrices

Below is another proof of one part in the [Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) (for the spectral norm) which states that:

$$
\mathbf{A_k} = \underset{rank(\mathbf{B})=k}{argmin}\ \vert\vert\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{B}\vert\vert_2,
$$

(the proof can be found in this [book](https://mml-book.github.io/), it uses the same notation as in the Wikipedia's link above, except matrices and vectors are in bold face).

> If we assume that there is another matrix $\mathbf{B}$ with
> $rank(\mathbf{B}) \le k$, such that
>
> $||\mathbf{A} − \mathbf{B}||_2 \lt ||\mathbf{A}−\mathbf{A}_k||_2$,
>
> then there exists an at least $(n − k)$-dimensional null space $Z \subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$, such that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{Z}$ implies that $\mathbf{Bx} = \mathbf{0}$.
> Then it follows that,
>
> $||\mathbf{Ax}||_2 = ||(\mathbf{A} − \mathbf{B})\mathbf{x}||_2$,
>
> and by using a version of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality that encompasses norms of matrices, we obtain
>
> $$ \lvert\vert \mathbf{Ax} \rvert\vert_2 \le \vert\vert \mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B} \vert\vert_2 \vert\vert \mathbf{x}\vert\vert_2\lt\sigma_{k+1}\ \vert\vert \mathbf{x}\vert\vert_2.$$
>
> However, there exists a $(k + 1)$-dimensional subspace where
> $\vert\vert\mathbf{Ax}\vert\vert_2 \ge \sigma_{k+1}\vert\vert\mathbf{x}\vert\vert_2$, which is spanned by the
> right-singular vectors $\mathbf{v}_j$ , $j \le k + 1$ of $\mathbf{A}$. Adding
> up dimensions of these two spaces yields a number greater than $n$, as
> there must be a nonzero vector in both spaces. This is a contradiction
> of the rank-nullity theorem.

The penultimate sentence makes me confused as to why the sum of two spaces' dimensions being greater than $n$ is a contradiction to rank-nullity theorem.

My understanding is that the two subspaces to add up dimensions are: The at-least $(n-k)$-dimensional null space $Z$ and the $(k+1)$-dimensional space spanned by the right-singular vectors $\mathbf{v}_j$, $j \le k+1$. And so the dimensions do add up to more than $n$, but how can we be sure that the latter $(k+1)$-dimensional space is a subspace of the range of $\mathbf{B}$ so that we can arrive at the contradiction to the rank-nullity theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a good point; I don't see how to relate this to the map $B$. I'd say it's rather a contradiction to general dimension principles.

What do we know? If $x$ is a nonzero vector in our first subspace $Z$ then we have $\|Ax\|_2<\sigma_{k+1}\|x\|_2$, so $x$ cannot lie in the other subspace wherein $\|Ax\|_2\ge\sigma_{k+1}\|x\|_2$ would hold. The two subspaces you mention then intersect only at zero; there is an internal direct sum!

Hence $n$ is greater than or equal to the dimension of this subspace - the direct sum - and that dimension is nothing but the sum of dimensions, which is greater than or equal to $n-k+k+1=n+1$. But $n\ge n+1$ is absurd, so there's your contradiction.

You *can* prove $\dim(A\oplus B)=\dim(A)+\dim(B)$ using the rank nullity theorem but I doubt that that's what they meant. I guess the authors just had "general dimension theory" in their heads and that's what they meant to say.